# Kosaraju's Algorithm for spoj's BOTTOM

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am trying to solve http://www.spoj.com/problems/BOTTOM/

Here are the steps I am following:

1) Find the strongly connected components using Kosaraju's algorithm. 2) Consider a strongly connected component. Consider an edge u. Now consider all edges from u to some vertice v. If v lies in some other SCC, eliminate the whole strongly conected component. Else include all the elements in the solution.

However, I am constantly getting WA. Please help.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;
int k = 0;
int V, E;
bool fix[5001];
bool fix2[5001];
int compNum[5001];

void dfs(int v, vector< vector<int> >&G, bool *fix, vector <int> &out) {
    fix[v] = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < G[v].size(); i++) {
        int u = G[v][i];
        if (!fix[u]) {
            fix[u] = true;
            dfs(u, G, fix, out);
        }
    }
    out.push_back(v);
}

void dfs2(int v, vector< vector<int> >&G, bool *fix2, vector < vector<int> > &components) {
    fix2[v] = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < G[v].size(); i++) {
        int u = G[v][i];
        if (!fix2[u]) {
            fix2[u] = true;
            dfs2(u, G, fix2, components);
        }
    }
    components[k].push_back(v);
    compNum[v] = k;
}

int main() {
    int a, b;

    while (true) {

        cin >> V; if (V == 0) break; cin >> E;
        vector< vector<int> >G(V + 1);
        vector< vector<int> >G2(V + 1);

        vector<int>out;
        vector < vector<int> >components(V + 1);


        for (int i = 0; i < E; i++) {
            cin >> a >> b;
            G[a].push_back(b);
            G2[b].push_back(a);
        }



        for (int i = 1; i <= V; i++) {
            if (!fix[i])
                dfs(i, G, fix, out);
        }

        reverse(out.begin(), out.end());

        for (int i = 0; i < out.size(); i++){
            if (!fix2[out[i]]) {
                dfs2(out[i], G2, fix2, components);
                k++;
            }
        }

        vector<int>gamotana;

        for (int i = 0; i < components.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < components[i].size(); j++) {
                bool check = true;
                for (int z = 0; z < G[components[i][j]].size(); z++)
                {
                    if (compNum[G[components[i][j]][z]] != i)
                    {
                        check = false; goto next123;
                    }
                }
                if (check)
                    gamotana.push_back(components[i][j]);
            }
        next123:;
        }

            sort(gamotana.begin(), gamotana.end());

        for (int i = 0; i < gamotana.size(); i++)
            cout << gamotana[i] << " ";

        for (int i = 0; i < 5001; i++) {
            fix[i] = false;
            fix2[i] = false;
            compNum[i] = -1;
        }
        k = 0;

        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: For all we know, you could be making a silly mistake, like handling edge cases (0 or 1 vertices) incorrectly or printing the output incorrectly (an extra space here or there, stc). SO isn't the best place for vague questions when you still dont know where your bug is located and just post the whole program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your algorithm description you say you eliminate the entire connected component if some edge leads to a different component.

However, in your code you appear to add all vertices j in component i to your solution until you find an edge leading out.  In other words, even if a component is not a sink you may still incorrectly report some of the vertices as being sinks.

I imagine you should do something more like this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < components.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < components[i].size(); j++) {

            for (int z = 0; z < G[components[i][j]].size(); z++)
            {
                if (compNum[G[components[i][j]][z]] != i)
                {
                    goto next123;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < components[i].size(); j++)
            gamotana.push_back(components[i][j]);

    next123:;
    }
```

Of course, there may be more issues.  I would recommend you try constructing and testing some small examples first, and perhaps testing against a brute force solver to identify failing cases.

Comment: cant thank you enough for explaining! got AC, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

void dfs(vector<int>* edges, stack<int>& finishedVertices, bool* visited, int n, int start){
    visited[start] = true;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < edges[start].size() ; i++){
        int node = edges[start][i];
        if(!visited[node]){
            dfs(edges, finishedVertices, visited, n, node);
        }
    }
    finishedVertices.push(start);
}

void dfs_reverse(vector<int>* edgesT, bool* visited, unordered_map<int,vector<int>>& SCC, int node, int k){
    SCC[k].push_back(node);
    visited[node] = true;

    for(int i = 0 ; i < edgesT[node].size() ; i++){
        int new_node = edgesT[node][i];
        if(!visited[new_node]){
            dfs_reverse(edgesT, visited, SCC, new_node, k);
        }
    }
}

void getSCC(vector<int>* edges, vector<int>* edgesT, int n){
    bool* visited = new bool[n];
    for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++){
        visited[i] = false;
    }

    stack<int> finishedVertices;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++){
        if(!visited[i]){
            dfs(edges, finishedVertices, visited, n, i);
        }
    }

    unordered_map<int,vector<int>> SCC;
    int k = 0;

    for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++){
        visited[i] = false;
    }

    while(!finishedVertices.empty()){
        int node = finishedVertices.top();
        finishedVertices.pop();

        if(!visited[node]){
            dfs_reverse(edgesT, visited, SCC, node, k);
            k++;
        }
    }

    int flag = 1;
    vector<int> ans;
    vector<int> bottom;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < k ; i++){
        for(int j = 0 ; j < SCC[i].size(); j++){
            ans.push_back(SCC[i][j]);
        }
        for(int m = 0 ; m < ans.size() ; m++){
            int node = ans[m];
            for(int j = 0 ; j < edges[node].size() ; j++){
                int new_node = edges[node][j];
                vector<int> :: iterator it;
                it = find(ans.begin(), ans.end(), new_node);
                if(it == ans.end()){
                    flag = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(flag == 0)
                break;
        }
        if(flag == 1){
            for(int j = 0 ; j < ans.size() ; j++)
                bottom.push_back(ans[j]);
        }
        flag = 1;
        ans.clear();
    }
    sort(bottom.begin(), bottom.end());
    for(int i = 0 ; i < bottom.size() ; i++)
        cout << bottom[i] + 1 << " ";
    cout << endl;
}

int main(){
    while(true){
        int n;
        cin >> n;
        if(n == 0)
            break;

        vector<int>* edges = new vector<int>[n];
        vector<int>* edgesT = new vector<int>[n];
        int e;
        cin >> e;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < e ; i++){
            int x, y;
            cin >> x >> y;
            edges[x-1].push_back(y-1);
            edgesT[y-1].push_back(x-1);
        }

        getSCC(edges, edgesT, n);

        delete [] edges;
        delete [] edgesT;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't use memset in your code as it doesn't work sometime so instead write you own function or code.